# input type file exceeds its width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have styled a file selector but the problem is it exceeds its max-width from the parent container

Everything works fine here but run this code on browser you'll see that the input type file will exceed its limit

[image]

I have also attached my code

```css
.inputcontainer
{
width:500px;
margin:0 auto;
padding:0;
}
.filess
{
text-align:center; 
width:200px; 
margin:auto; 
border:none;
position:relative;
} 
.filess .file_upload
{
max-width:150px; 
width:100%; 
height:35px;
padding-top:6px; 
background:#f55282; 
color:#fff; 
display:inline-block; 
margin:0 auto 20px; 
cursor:pointer;
font-size:19px;
}
.filess .file_upload input[type="file"]
{
position:absolute; 
height:100%; 
width:100%; 
opacity:0; 
top:0;  
left:0;
cursor:pointer;
}
.filess span
{
float:left; 
text-align:center; 
margin:auto; 
display:inline-block;
}
.filess span.delt_head 
{
float:right; 
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputcontainer">
<div class="filess">
<span class="delt_head"><i>Delete</i></span>
<span class="file_upload"><input type="file" /> Choose a file</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: see the screenshot

Comment: It may be your browser problem. please check on other browsers.

Comment: I'm working on firefox browser now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a problem with overflow try `overflow:hidden` for the `file` element.

so that it will wrap around its parent container.

```css
.inputcontainer
{
width:500px;
margin:0 auto;
padding:0;
}
.filess
{
text-align:center; 
width:200px; 
margin:auto; 
border:none;
position:relative;
} 
.filess .file_upload
{
max-width:150px; 
width:100%; 
height:35px;
padding-top:6px; 
background:#f55282; 
color:#fff; 
display:inline-block; 
margin:0 auto 20px; 
cursor:pointer;
font-size:19px;
}
.filess .file_upload input[type="file"]
{
position:absolute; 
height:100%; 
width:100%; 
opacity:0; 
top:0;  
left:0;
cursor:pointer;
overflow:hidden;
}
.filess span
{
float:left; 
text-align:center; 
margin:auto; 
display:inline-block;
}
.filess span.delt_head 
{
float:right; 
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputcontainer">
<div class="filess">
<span class="delt_head"><i>Delete</i></span>
<span class="file_upload"><input type="file" /> Choose a file</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thnx for fast reply I'll go check this.